# Cannot find dynamic class reference PHP

Tags: php

My routing.php (auto-prepend file)

```
<?php
if (preg_match('/\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) {
    return false;
} else {
    include 'index.php';
}
```

My index.php

```
<?php

namespace MVC;
require_once "controllers/AdminController.php";
use MVC\controllers\AdminController as AdminController;

/*
 * Break the requested URI down into an array
 */

$request = trim($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
$request = explode("/", $request);
$request = array_filter($request);

$additional = array();
$singles = array();

/*
 * Get the method/controller from the requested URL
 */

foreach($request as $key=>$item) {
    switch($key) {
        case 1:
            $controller = $item;
            break;
        case 2:
            $method = $item;
            break;
        default:
            if($key > 2) {
                $item = explode("=", $item);
                if(isset($item[1])) {
                    //key item pair, data
                    $pairs[$item[0]] = $item[1];

                    /*
                     * Make the assumption that any value passed in
                     * as an assigned value is data and not a route
                     *
                     * Append this to the pairs array as its own key/item
                     */
                } else if(isset($item[0])) {
                    echo "<b>WARNING: \"" . $item[0] . "\" has no key/value!</b>";
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}

/*
 * Handle the fact that these might not have been requested
 */


if(!isset($controller))
    $controller = 'index';

$controller = ucfirst($controller) . "Controller";

if(!isset($method))
    $method = 'index';

$controller = new $controller();
```

My AdminController.php (found in controllers/AdminController.php)

```
<?php

namespace MVC\controllers;

require_once "libs/Controller.php";
use MVC\libs\Controller;

class AdminController extends Controller {

}
```

Finally my Controller superclass found in libs/Controller.php

```
<?php

namespace MVC\libs;

class Controller {

}
```

My issue is this line

```
$controller = new $controller();
```

I'm aware that this is a variable - that's the intention, I'm trying to dynamically load this class based on the URI request.

Gives this error:

```
127.0.0.1:50342 [500]: /admin/users/id=555/action=ban - Class 'AdminController' not found in /home/jack/PhpstormProjects/mvc/index.php on line 64
```

I've checked that it's requiring the class, using it as "AdminController", yet it still can't find a reference to it in the relevant namespace - I'm thinking that because it's dynamic it might have some issues?

Cheers all!

EDIT: My folder structure

```
controllers
   AdminController.php
libs
   Controller.php
index.php
routing.php
```

Comment: TBH, I'm not very good with classes, but shouldn't `$controller = new $controller();` be `$controller = new Controller();`?

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I'm trying to dynamically load the requested controller - which is held in a variable state.

Comment: Have you tried manually doing `$controller = new AdminController();` just to make sure that works properly? I don't think the dynamic variable is the issue, I believe you have some other issue going on. Troubleshoot with manual instantiation first.

Comment: It works fine with new AdminController() @JoeCoder

Comment: @JoeCoder he's trying to dynamically call the class name, doing `$controller = new AdminController()` would be 'hardcoded' in.

Comment: " just to make sure that works properly" ????

Comment: Ah okay. Well instead of setting a string to a value to call the controller, why not do something like `if ($string == 'AdminController') { $controller = new AdminController(); }` or something similar. Could use case too

Comment: As you said yourself josh I don't want anything hardcoding in, i just want it to load the relevant controller (if it exists) from what it gets from the URI :P @Cherryade

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a namespace problem. You can't use variable class name **and** `use` statement at the same time like you do. Your variable gets its value at runtime, while `use` imports are done at compile time (`use` can't be used in block scope for the same reason). See:

```
use foo as bar;

class foo {
   public function __construct() {
      echo "OK\n";
   }
}

new foo(); // OK
new bar(); // OK

$foo = 'foo';
$bar = 'bar';

new $foo(); // OK
new $bar(); // Fatal error: Class 'bar' not found
```

Solution: use full class name (with absolute namespace) in your variable.

Comment: So this? 
$controller = new \MVC\controllers\$controller(); - it gives a syntax error, that's how I'd normally write it with reference to AdminController (new \MVC\controllers\AdminController(); - thanks for the answer though!

Comment: Either set `$controller` to full class name before calling `new`, or use `new \MVC\controllers\{$controller}();` (notice the braces).